# How can i get the average value form of columns form my sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, average

Hi I am working with sqlite. I alredy stored some fields in sqlite when i retrving the data the average values not assigned the values.

```
cursor = database.rawQuery("Select '"+start+"' as dateadded ,AVG('ch4') as 'ch4',AVG('c2h2') as 'c2h2',AVG('c2h4') as 'c2h4' where dateAdded between '"+start+"' and '"+end+"' and '"+edd+"' = '"+equipid+"' ",null);
```

I wrote like this it is return the value but that is not correct. I think the problem is i am not wrote any table name.

When i executing the code in the sqlite that is return only dateadded and remaning all are null.

```
Select '02-07-14 11:58' as dateadded ,AVG('ch4') as ch4,AVG('c2h2') as c2h2,AVG('c2h4') as c2h4 where dateAdded between '02-07-14 11:58' and '03-07-14 11:58' and "equipid" = '2'
```

If i write the code like

```
Select '02-07-14 11:58' as dateadded ,AVG('ch4') as ch4,AVG('c2h2') as c2h2,AVG('c2h4') as c2h4 where dateAdded between '02-07-14 11:58' and '03-07-14 11:58' and "equipid" = '2' FROM dgadata
```

The dgadata is the table name. But that is showing the like

```
Error:near "FROM": syntax error:
```

So can you please tell me how can i write the query for average of values in android sqlite.

Thank You

Shankar

Comment: are you sure you have these columns: ch4 c2h2...?

Answer (score 2):

You have a wron syntax.
You use

```
SELECT ... WHERE ...FROM...
```

Correct is

```
SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE ...
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_c-SDSO63obT1hvdGNfc2xCQVU/edit?usp=sharing    Select '02-07-14 11:58' as dateadded ,AVG('ch4') as ch4,AVG('c2h2') as c2h2,AVG('c2h4') as c2h4 FROM dgadata where dateAdded between '02-07-14 11:58' and '03-07-14 11:58' and "equipid" = '2'   But i got all 0.0s

Comment: @user3783376 is ch4 a `string` or a numerical value in you DB?

Comment: That is interger:  "+H2+" integer,"+CH4+" integer,"+C2H2+" integer,"+C2H4+" integer,"+

Comment: @user3783376 and these values are all not null?

Comment: Ok thanks The query is like this: Select '02-07-14 11:58' as dateadded ,AVG(ch4) as ch4,AVG(c2h2) as c2h2,AVG(c2h4) as c2h4 FROM dgadata where "equipid" = '2' ........ Before that i putted AVG('c2h4') that is not accepted.

Comment: But AVG('c2h4') means AVG of string c2h4 not of a column value!

Comment: @Nava2011 if you use avg funktion you also have to add a `group by` clause for instance `group by dateAdded`

Answer (score 0):

Select '02-07-14 11:58' as dateadded ,AVG('ch4') as ch4,AVG('c2h2') as c2h2,AVG('c2h4') as c2h4 where dateAdded between '02-07-14 11:58' and '03-07-14 11:58' and "equipid" = '2'

in this query please add from tablename before where

ex

select '02-07-14 11:58' as dateadded from tablename where  dateAdded between '02-07-14 11:58' and '03-07-14 11:58' and "equipid" = '2'

Comment: Select '02-07-14 11:58' as dateadded ,AVG('ch4') as ch4,AVG('c2h2') as c2h2,AVG('c2h4') as c2h4 FROM dgadata where dateAdded between '02-07-14 11:58' and '03-07-14 11:58' and "equipid" = '2'   i wrote but when i select all the values get 0.0